# Find different percentile for every group in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, quantile, percentile

I have the date frame with the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP_ID': np.random.randint(1, 7, size=100),
                     'VALUES': np.random.randint(0, 50, size=100)})
df['THRESHOLD'] = df['GROUP_ID']*5
df = df[['GROUP_ID','VALUES','THRESHOLD']]
df.sort_values(by='GROUP_ID', inplace=True)
```

(this one is just for example)

A column THRESHOLD is actually a percentile (in %) for every group.
And I need to add a column 'PERCENTILE' in which there should be a numerical value of percentile for values in each group.

I was trying to use `groupby` and `apply`, but I don't get how to pass values of THRESHOLD column to parameter `q` in `quantile\percentile` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary and map treshold with `x.name` for `GROUP_ID` passed to function [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column with [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html), only necessary treshold between 0 and 1:

```
np.random.seed(152)
df = pd.DataFrame({'GROUP_ID': np.random.randint(1, 7, size=100),
                     'VALUES': np.random.randint(0, 50, size=100)})
df['THRESHOLD'] = df['GROUP_ID'] / 15
df = df[['GROUP_ID','VALUES','THRESHOLD']]
df.sort_values(by='GROUP_ID', inplace=True)

d = dict(zip(df['GROUP_ID'], df['THRESHOLD']))
df['new'] = df.groupby('GROUP_ID')['VALUES'].transform(lambda x: x.quantile(d[x.name]))
print (df.head(20))
    GROUP_ID  VALUES  THRESHOLD       new
23         1      17   0.066667  7.733333
53         1       9   0.066667  7.733333
39         1      43   0.066667  7.733333
57         1      15   0.066667  7.733333
36         1      47   0.066667  7.733333
59         1      17   0.066667  7.733333
28         1       4   0.066667  7.733333
63         1      33   0.066667  7.733333
18         1      12   0.066667  7.733333
12         1      27   0.066667  7.733333
47         1      43   0.066667  7.733333
81         1      45   0.066667  7.733333
91         1      45   0.066667  7.733333
5          1       8   0.066667  7.733333
83         1      26   0.066667  7.733333
61         2      39   0.133333  4.200000
95         2      33   0.133333  4.200000
44         2      22   0.133333  4.200000
42         2      34   0.133333  4.200000
41         2      48   0.133333  4.200000
```

Comment: Why this gives me only `NaN`s ?
```df['PERCENTILE'] = df.groupby('GROUP_ID')['VALUES'].apply(lambda x: x.quantile(d[x.name]/100))```

Comment: @DenisKa - Maybe data dependent issue? `THRESHOLD` column has to be between `0 and 1`

Comment: No. I get - thats because `groupby` returns `Series` of 7 values. How should i translate them to another column now?